# Wait for async data to load and scroll div accordingly in Vue 3 with Composition API

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm creating a chat widget and I need my component ref=chatBody to scroll to the bottom of the div every time a new chat message shows. For the back-end this means every time my chatSession.events length is bigger than before. In order to do that I have created a watch that triggers a function every time this happens but is not working as expected. When the component is mounted it works but whenever I add a message (the chatSession.events array changes) is not working. I'm pretty sure is due to the asynchronous nature of the data but since I'm evaluating a computed property (the array length) inside that watch I'm surprise this is not working.

```
<template>
  <div class="flex-col flex-nowrap">
    <BaseTranslationBar />
    <div id="chat-body" ref="chatBody" class="overflow-y-auto p-2">
      <ul id="chatBox" class="mt-4">
        <BaseChatMessage
          v-for="(chatMessage, index) in chatSession.events"
          :chatMessage="chatMessage"
          :key="index"
          :chatSession="chatSession"
          :class="{ 'mt-0': index === 0, 'mt-4': index > 0 }"
        />
      </ul>
    </div>
    <form @submit.prevent="sendMessage" class="chat-form relative mt-6">
      <textarea
        class="chat-textarea h-[160px] py-4"
        placeholder="Add your message here..."
        type="text"
        v-model="message"
      />
      <div
        class="chat-input-buttons flex justify-end absolute bottom-0 right-0 pb-4"
      >
        <button
          class="flex flex-col justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring"
        >
          <i class="chat-input-button fa-paperclip fas text-blue-500"></i>
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          value="Send"
          class="flex flex-col justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring"
        >
          <i class="chat-input-button fa-paper-plane fas text-blue-500"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <BasePythiaBar class="mt-4" />
    <BaseChatButtonRow :chatId="chatSession.id" class="mt-4" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, ref, onMounted, watch } from "vue";
import ChatService from "@/services/ChatService.js";
import BaseChatMessage from "@/components/BaseChatMessage.vue";
import BaseTranslationBar from "@/components/BaseTranslationBar.vue";
import BasePythiaBar from "@/components/BasePythiaBar.vue";
import BaseChatButtonRow from "@/components/BaseChatButtonRow.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    BaseChatMessage,
    BaseChatButtonRow,
    BasePythiaBar,
    BaseTranslationBar,
  },
  props: {
    chatSession: {
      type: Object,
      default: function () {
        return {};
      },
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const message = ref("");
    const chatBody = ref(null);
    const chatSessionsLength = computed(() => props.chatSession.events.length);
    onMounted(() => {
      scrollChatBodyToEnd(chatBody.value);
    });
    watch(chatSessionsLength, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      if (newValue > oldValue) {
        scrollChatBodyToEnd();
      }
    });
    const scrollChatBodyToEnd = () => {
      console.log("Scrolling");
      chatBody.value.scrollTop = chatBody.value.scrollHeight;
    };
    const sendMessage = () => {
      const messageObject = {
        aggregateId: props.chatSession.id,
        message: message.value,
        agentId: props.chatSession.agentId,
        skippedValidationErrors: [],
      };
      ChatService.sendChatMessage(messageObject);
      scrollChatBodyToEnd();
      message.value = "";
    };
    return {
      message,
      sendMessage,
      chatBody,
      scrollChatBodyToEnd,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try to watch it deeply? You can do this by adding `deep: true` option to the watcher. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers
If that doesn't work, try watching `chatSessionsLength.value` instead. Or try both.

Comment: Thanks @Duha please check my comment on Gabe's answer ref. deep watchers. ChatSessionLength is not a reactive  state, it can't be use inside a watcher. In order to test your suggestion anyways I changed to a ref but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up noticing that I don't really need a watcher if I call the scrollChatBodyToEnd() method when the chat component is updating (using the lifecycle hook) the div scrolls to the bottom everytime the component's DOM change (a message is added to the dom = showed in the chat). So I ended up with something like this in my setup function:

```
setup(props) {
    const message = ref("");
    const chatBody = ref(null);
    const chatSessionProp = ref(computed(() => props.chatSession));
    onMounted(() => {
      scrollChatBodyToEnd();
    });
    onUpdated(() => {
      scrollChatBodyToEnd();
    });
    const scrollChatBodyToEnd = () => {
      if (chatBody.value && chatSessionProp.value != null) {
        console.log(chatSessionProp.value);
        chatBody.value.scrollTop = chatBody.value.scrollHeight;
      }
    };
    const sendMessage = () => {
      const messageObject = {
        aggregateId: props.chatSession.id,
        message: message.value,
        agentId: props.chatSession.agentId,
        skippedValidationErrors: [],
      };
      ChatService.sendChatMessage(messageObject);
      scrollChatBodyToEnd();
      message.value = "";
    };
    return {
      message,
      sendMessage,
      chatBody,
      scrollChatBodyToEnd,
      chatSessionProp,
      // getChatSessionEvents,
      // test,
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather deep watch `chatSession`. Like:

```
watch(chatSession, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  if (newValue.events.length > oldValue.events.length) {
    scrollChatBodyToEnd();
  }
}, { deep: true});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Gabe. If I deep watch chatSession the newValue and the oldValue will be the same, this is kind of a popular caveat with watch to my surprise. I'm still trying to figure out how to deal with that in order to test your approach. Any ideas ?

Comment: O, I did not know that. Then I would just skip the if-statement and run the `scrollChatBodyToEnd()` anytime the `chatSession` object changes. Looking at the functionality, in most cases it would be called anyways, wouldn't it?

Comment: you are totally right. Unfortunately I get the same results, the watcher actually...watch the array of objects and reacts to every change but the scroll do not wait for async data (eg. when a message comes back from the backend).  I just don't understand why since I'm watching a prop that in theory is reactive (props.chatSession).

Comment: Hmm, yeah, maybe you could make a computed property for the prop? Don't know, sometimes that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Gabe. I actually tried that and also with a getter but didn't work. I'm sure now that is an asynchronicity issue. If I wrap the scroll functionality into a set time out it works. I just don't know how to be sure that the prop is already there in order to trigger the scroll functionality.